# How do I make one form show up when my link is visited?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I created a register/login page that redirects to a to do list website that I created. However, when you first click on my link, both the login and register forms show up. I only want the sign in form to show up first (if someone needs to register, there is an anchor tag at the bottom of the sign in form that redirects to the register form). What do I need to change in my code to make only the sign in form show up when the link is visited?

link: https://capstone-project-with-login.herokuapp.com/

**Code:**

```js
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login");
const createAccountForm = document.getElementById("register");
const registerLink = document.getElementById("register-link");
const signInLink = document.getElementById("sign-in-link");

loginForm.style.display = "inline-block";
createAccountForm.style.display = "none";

registerLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("entered");
  loginForm.style.display = "none";
  createAccountForm.style.display = "inline-block";
});

signInLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
  loginForm.style.display = "inline-block";
  createAccountForm.style.display = "none";
});

function store() {
  let name = document.getElementById("name");
  let pw = document.getElementById("pw");
  let lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  let upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  let numbers = /[0-9]/g;

  if (name.value.length == 0) {
    alert("Please fill in email");
  } else if (pw.value.length == 0) {
    alert("Please fill in password");
  } else if (name.value.length == 0 && pw.value.length == 0) {
    alert("Please fill in email and password");
  } else if (pw.value.length > 8) {
    alert("Max of 8");
  } else if (!pw.value.match(numbers)) {
    alert("please add 1 number");
  } else if (!pw.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {
    alert("please add 1 uppercase letter");
  } else if (!pw.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    alert("please add 1 lovercase letter");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("name", name.value);
    localStorage.setItem("pw", pw.value);
    alert("Your account has been created");
    window.location = "toDoList.html";
    return false;
  }
}

//checking
function check() {
  let storedName = localStorage.getItem("name");
  let storedPw = localStorage.getItem("pw");

  let userName = document.getElementById("userName");
  let userPw = document.getElementById("userPw");
  let userRemember = document.getElementById("rememberMe");

  if (userName.value == storedName && userPw.value == storedPw) {
    window.location = "toDoList.html";
    alert("You are logged in.");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Error on login");
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: skyblue;
  color: white;
  font: 87.5%/1.5em "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

after {
  clear: both;
}

.login {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 320px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.login form {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 22px 22px 22px 22px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #282e33;
  border-top: 3px solid #434a52;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #434a52;
}

.login form span {
  background-color: #363b41;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  border-right: 3px solid #434a52;
  color: #606468;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.login form input[type="email"] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
}

.login form input[type="password"] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
}

.login form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #b5cd60;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#login form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #16aa56;
}

.register {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 320px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.register form {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 22px 22px 22px 22px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #282e33;
  border-top: 3px solid #434a52;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #434a52;
}

.register form span {
  background-color: #363b41;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  border-right: 3px solid #434a52;
  color: #606468;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.register form input[type="email"] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
}

.register form input[type="password"] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
}

.register form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #b5cd60;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#register form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #16aa56;
}

.form-register {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.form-login {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#sign-in-link {
  background-color: white;
}

a#sign-in-link:hover {
  background-color: rgb(177, 18, 18);
}

a#register-link {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

a#register-link:hover {
  background-color: rgb(182, 11, 11);
}
```

```html
<div id="register" class="register">
  <form name="form-register" id="form-register">
    <h1>REGISTER</h1>

    <label for="name">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="name" placeholder="Email" required />

    <label for="pw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="pw" placeholder="Password" required />

    <ul class="helper-text">
      <li class="length">Must be at least 8 characters long.</li>
      <li class="lowercase">Must contain a lowercase letter.</li>
      <li class="uppercase">Must contain an uppercase letter.</li>
      <li class="special">Must contain a number or special character.</li>
    </ul>
    <input id="rgstr_btn" type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return store()" />
    <a href="#form-login" id="sign-in-link">Already one of us?</a>
  </form>

</div>
<div id="login" class="login">
  <form name="form-login" id="form-login">
    <h1>SIGN IN</h1>

    <label for="userName">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="userName" placeholder="Email" required />

    <label for="userPw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="userPw" placeholder="Password" required />

    <div id="remember">
      <input type="checkbox" value="lsRememberMe" id="rememberMe" style="display: inline-block" />
      <label>Remember me</label>


      <input id="login_btn" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return check()" />

  </form>
  <a href="#form-register" id="register-link">New here?</a>

  </div>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Abbu, please read above comment from @Quentin

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try hiding signup form in the main function, then toggle it with event listeners (like below),

```
loginForm.style.display = "inline-block";
createAccountForm.style.display = "none";

registerLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("entered");
  loginForm.style.display = "none";
  createAccountForm.style.display = "inline-block";
});

signInLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
  loginForm.style.display = "inline-block";
  createAccountForm.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed this for an assignment!